# Wordpress: Include page content in header.php

Tags: wordpress

I want to include the content of an existing page in the header.php file? What's the easiest way to do this?  I am guessing that there is a way to load an existing page via a php call, however I am not sure of the correct syntax.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instantiate a new query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=7' );
```

After doing so, you make a loop to display the query's content.

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // Important, so this loop does not affect the global post object afterwards ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is based on WP's official codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Notice that the query targets a single page ID

Comment: Thanks for the help. So this seems to include only the title of the page and not the content - I would like the content as well?  Also, I think in the while loop, "$the_query" is supposed to be "$query"?  Thanks!

Comment: So adding, "the_content()" in place of "the_title()" seems to solve my issue. Thanks!

Comment: You are totally right. My mistake. And yes, once in the loop, you may add any template tag